# Android app update generates re-install reports in the Play Console statistics

Tags: android, google-play

I have an android app that I published last september on the play store. 
Since end of march, each new release I publish to production generates high number on uninstall an reinstall (according to the play console statistics).

This seems to have a strong impact on my app ranking.

Any idea of where it could come from ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Answering late but I hope it helps.

Seems like Huawei changed their device name from Huawei x to Huawei-x. This causes the uninstall/install events to happen until all Huawei phones the new device name.